# How to make press the keyboard return random python list elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a python list with some numbers in it and I want to achieve that press keyboard can return a different number. This is my code.

```
import random
import os
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
b = random.sample(a, 1)

while True:
    print(b)
    os.system('pause')
```

But everytime I press space the returned element is the same, how can I make it return a different number?

Comment: Have you tried moving the line that starts with `b = ...` into the `while` loop?

Comment: Building upon the previous comment, think about how many times b is getting assigned vs. how many times you want b to be assigned

Comment: Yes, I just tried it, it works, thanks ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import random
import os
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

while True:
    b = random.sample(a, 1)
    print(b)
    os.system('pause')
```

A random sample has to be taken every iteration